# import custom Windows event viewer logs form csv into sql table

Tags: java, sql-server, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, event-viewer

I have a powershell command taking event viewer logs from a remote windows server and putting it into a csv file and then displaying it and additionally adding it into the database (sql server)

```
String command = "powershell.exe cd 'Path\\Output'; "
        + "$password = get-content 'Path\\Output\\"
        + serverClicked + "' | convertto-securestring; $username = 'administrator'; "
        + "$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password); "
        + "Invoke-Command -ComputerName " + serverClicked + " -Credential $cred -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock "
        + "{ Get-EventLog -LogName " + logName + " -EntryType " + entryType + " -Newest 50 | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType}"
        + " | Out-File " + serverClicked + "." + logName + entryType + "." + curDate + ".csv; cat " + serverClicked + "." + logName + entryType + "." + curDate + ".csv";
System.out.println(command);

Process powerShellProcess;
powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
String line;
System.out.println("Output:");
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
ShowInfoTextArea.setText("\n");

//------------------------------------
//Going to try adding the data to the database
DBConnect d = new DBConnect();
Connection con = d.getConnection();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO EventViewer(TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType, PSComputerName) VALUES ('" + timeGenerated + "', '" + eventID + "', '" + message + "', '" + source + "', '" + entryType2 + "', '" + pSComputerName + "');");
System.out.println("INSERT INTO EventViewer(TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType, PSComputerName) VALUES ('" + timeGenerated + "', '" + eventID + "', '" + message + "', '" + source + "', '" + entryType2 + "', '" + pSComputerName + "');");
stmt.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
//------------------------------------
```

This code runs a powershell command and takes the output into a csv file and then i need to take that output and put it into separate fields into the database setup as:

```
[TimeGenerated] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EventID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
[Source] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EntryType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PSComputerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LogName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL
```

Either i need to figure out the Java to get it correctly into the database or a better way of doing it. The main problem i have faced is that the message part of the event is on multiple lines

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this but I could see an issue with your output line

> ```
> + " | Out-File " + serverClicked + "." + logName + entryType + "." + curDate + ".csv; cat " + serverClicked + "." + logName + entryType + "." + curDate + ".csv";
> ```

`Out-File` is not going to make a proper CSV and could also be introducing encoding issues. Also it looks like you are reading the file back in. If that is the case we can skip that step entirely by just using [`ConvertTo-CSV`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849878.aspx) which was designed to work with the object you are outputting from `Get-EventLog`. So I would change the last line of `command` to instead...

```
+ " |  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That should get you a working copy of what you are looking for. If I am on the right track and you still have issues I will need you to debug for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question. I will be checking this within the hour and debugging. Thanks again.

Comment: That worked for fixing the unformatted csv file, my main question now and back to the original is, how do i take that csv and input the fields into a sql table, i dont mind recreating that sql table, i would just like each event in the sql table. Please help me with this

Comment: I have managed to get the data into a CSV and then into SQL however, i cannot get PowerShell to add the LogName to the csv. I am running this command: 
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Baron-Server -Credential $cred -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock { Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Site,TimeGenerated, EventID, Message, Source, EntryType} |  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:/output.csv`